# как автоматически генерировать rnfc в webstorm?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webstorm

Как автоматически генерировать rnfc(React Native Functional Component) в WebStorm ,в visual Studio можно написать rnfc вылезит словарик,затем по нажатию enter сгенерирует код компонента,как так же в WebStorm???